# How to create a POI VBAMacroReader(POIFSFileSystem fs)

Tags: apache-poi

I currently have working code that does

```
 pkg = OPCPackage.open(stream);
 // process worksheets in pkg...
 mr = new VBAMacroReader(stream);
 // process macros
```

The problem is that the first call reads stream, and the second then cannot read it.  Work around is to create multiple BufferedInputReaders which works but is obviously all wrong.  Why scan the pkg twice in the first place?

What I should be doing is calling

```
new VBAMacroReader(pkg.somehowGetPOIFSFileSystem())
```

However, it is not at all clear what somehowGetPOIFSFileSystem() should be.

(I only have a stream as source, not a file, it is coming over the network.  Only needs to work for .xlsm, not .xls.  But obviously the macro part is binary.)

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at the `apache poi` source on how the `POIFSFileSystem` containing the `VBA` project is extracted there. For `*.xls` (`BIFF`) it is contained in whole binary file system. For `*.xlsm` (`OOXML`) [openOOXML](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/poi/tags/REL_4_1_0/src/java/org/apache/poi/poifs/macros/VBAMacroReader.java?view=markup#l101) extracts it from the `ZIP` filesystem via `ZipInputStream`. I don't think there is a way not processing the whole stream twice. Once for the workbook content and once for the VBA project content.

Comment: Sure, openOOXML processes the entire filestream.  But it sets the POIFSFileSystem fs.  And fs can be passed explicitly as a constructor.  So I am pretty sure it can be done once.  But traversing all the XSSFRelation.SHARED_STRINGS is not at all obvious.,